# Synchronize two instances of a managed bean in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, javabeans

I'm building an auction site in JSF for a project, and I need to handle multiple users bidding on an auction at the same time.
I have a request scoped new bid bean, that validates the bid amount (should be higher than the current price + a minimum interval) and then creates the bid and updates the price.
If multiple users try to bid at the same time, I need the bean to synchronize the requests (so the amount validation is always with the updated price), should I just add 'synchronized' to the method?

Comment: Please share some code as it will help in understanding what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Where do you store the actual price, in DB or in some bean?

Comment: Be aware when using synchronized on a clustered environment. It will only work at each node level of the cluster.

Comment: Wrong path. This isn't the responsibilty of any frontend framework. Answer depends on service/backend framework you're using.

Comment: Like he says, your web application in and of itself should not be responsible for ensuring the orderly arrival of bids. You should design a data structure or some queuing system that will handle the orderly placement of bids

Comment: Sidenode: `Synchronized` Keyword for methods fails on Container-Managed Beans (there are multiple instances, `synchronized` just prevents two threads accessing the method on the same instance). If you need to synchronize a method access throughout all instances of a certain Bean-Type, you need to use a `private static` property, on which you put a lock (using `synchronized(this.object){ ...}` - or just use the `ApplicationScope` or a `Singleton` along with a synchronized method.

Comment: @BalusC What exactly do mean by that? I'm storing the values in a MySQL DB, and I'm using Apache Tomcat as the server. Should the synchronizing mechanism be on one of them instead of the web app?

Comment: Example of a proper service framework is EJB, already provided out the box on a real Java EE container. Its competitor, Spring, is however more often seen with Tomcat users, because that's "easier" than replacing Tomcat by a real Java EE container like TomEE, WildFly, GlassFish, etc.